# How to get the half portion of 3D data in Digital Reconstructed Radiography

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, vtk, itk

I have used `ITKRayCastInterpolateImageFunction` to generate DRR. I have given `axial CT` slices and rotated to `sagittal` and it is displaying fine. But i only need the **half portion of the sagittal image**(either left or right half).How can i select only a particular half part in the sagittal image?Is there any function in ITK or VTK that support this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a job for [region of interest filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1RegionOfInterestImageFilter.html). It is up to you whether you want to generate DRR of the entire 3D image, and then crop it, or crop the 3D image and then generate DRR.